# Validating two dropdowns in a single anchor tag click event

Tags: jquery

I have to validate two dropdowns in an anchor tag click event.

```
$(".viewmore").on('click',function(event){
    return   requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".color"));
    return   requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".size"));

});
function requiredValidation(ddl) {

    ddl = $(ddl);

    var isValid = true;
    if (jQuery.trim(ddl.val()) == 'VÆLG' ) {
        isValid = false;
        ddl.addClass("error");

    }
    else {
        ddl.removeClass("error");
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

but only first one is validating here.can any one give any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(".viewmore").on('click',function(event) {
    var valid1 =  requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".color"));
    var valid2 =   requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".size"));
    return valid1 && valid2;
});
```

You were returning soon after the first select was validated, you need to validate both the input fields then combine the result

Answer (score -1):

You have two return statements in the function for one thing. Therefore, only the first one is actually going to execute and return. That said, why are you returning at all? Depending on what you want to do upon validation or lack thereof, you may want to show an error message or something of the sort if it fails validation.

```
if (!requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".color")))
   alert("Error: color");
if (!requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".size")))
   alert("Error: size");
```